# WebSocket connection to 'wss://...path' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 in Blazor SignalR

Tags: blazor, signalr

I am using Signalr and it works properly in http://hostname but when i converted it to https:// it shows me this error and because of that i got CORS error.

"Access to fetch at 'https://...path' from origin 'https://...path' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Can any one help me to find out the solution for this problem?